# How to rotate an object to point along a vector Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

Hi I have been searching google for some time now with no avail. I was wondering if there was some function or easy way to make an object rotate so it is pointing along a certain vector (in this case, pointing the same way it is moving, but I would like to know generally how to do this with any Vector3) in Unity? I know it is possible to rotate an object using a Vector3 holding EulerAngles, but that is not what I'm looking for, since the object will not point in the direction of that Vector in 3D space.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should be able to use either [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) or [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to accomplish your goal.

Additionally, here is a [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/803365/make-the-player-face-his-movement-direction.html) to a good Unity answers post where they use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to get a character to face the position it's moving based on its vertical and horizontal movement input.

Answer (score 2):

```
transform.forward = velocity.normalized;
```

Hope that helps =)